# Deauthorize an app

Tags: applications, google-account, permissions

I installed [MightyText](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.texty.sms) the other day.

But I haven't used it so I uninstalled it.

Then I remembered it required links to my Google account - so I went to [Google Account security](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens).

But it doesn't list the app - when I reinstall MightyText it doesn't prompt me for authorization again - it says it's "linked". There is an "unlink" button - but I have no way of knowing if it actually does it.

Where can I find the Google interface to revoke this permission?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your app doesn't do Oauth/OpenId, instead it uses Android's integrated auth model via a special permission:

```
YOUR ACCOUNTS
USE THE AUTHENTICATION CREDENTIALS OF AN ACCOUNT
Allows the app to request authentication tokens.
```

[ColorNote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.socialnmobile.dictapps.notepad.color.note), for example, doesn't need this permission and thus must get an auth token via the browser. It ends up in the list in the link you provided if you authorize it and you can revoke given permission for ColorNote via your assumed method.

That's why you won't find Google's Drive, Youtube, Maps and so on in the list either as they also use Android's integrated auth token permission.

Pro/Cons:

- Integrated: less friction for the user, depends on Google Apps and a Google account
- OpenId: no Google Apps required, works with accounts from any OpenID provider (see [this site](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/login?noauto=true&returlUrl=/users/current)'s login support for any provider)

Answer (score 1):

Answering a two year old question since this is the first link I found.

You go here:
https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

You can find under your account settings than security tab.
The above link will help since it is a bit tricky to find.

I hope this helps someone in the future!